# Angular.io property with null value throwing undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript

Working with Angular, and trying to push data to a form where some of the data is null. When attempting to map the data model, I'm having issues where exceptions are thrown when the incoming data property is null.

Here is my input data class:

```
export class Inputdata {
  sweepId: string;
  IndivId: string;
  FirstName: string;
  PrefName: string;
  LastName: string;
  Suffix: string;
  Language: string;
  Addr1: string;
  Addr2: string;
  Addr3: string;
  City: string;
  State: string;
  Zip: string;
  CountryCode: string;
  Country: string;
  PrimaryPhoneType: string;
  PrimaryPhone: string;
  PrimaryEmailType: string;
  PrimaryEmail: string;
  Positioncode: string;
  TrackingNumber: string;
  PositionTitle: string;
  AreaServed: string;
  DistrictServed: string;
  TrackingID: string;
}
```

The data moves across from the database to the angular service just fine and gets to the component as an object called `data` which is an array of type `Inputdata`. In the subscribe call, I'm assigning data across from Inputdata to the Person data type like this:

```
 this.people.getPersonById(this.Id).subscribe(data=>{
     this.inputs = data;
     console.log(this.inputs[0]);
     this.person.email.priEmailType = this.inputs[0].PrimaryEmailType || 'Not Provided';
     this.person.email.emailAddress = this.inputs[0].PrimaryEmail;
     this.person.phone.priPhoneType = this.inputs[0].PrimaryPhoneType;
     this.person.phone.Phone = this.inputs[0].PrimaryPhone;
     this.person.name.firstName = this.inputs[0].FirstName;
     this.person.name.prefName = this.inputs[0].PrefName;
     this.person.name.lastName = this.inputs[0].LastName;
     this.person.name.suffix = this.inputs[0].Suffix;
     this.person.address.addr1 = this.inputs[0].Addr1;
     this.person.address.addr2 = this.inputs[0].Addr2;
     this.person.address.addr3 = this.inputs[0].Addr3;
     this.person.address.city = this.inputs[0].City;
     this.person.address.state = this.inputs[0].State;
     this.person.address.zip = this.inputs[0].Zip;
     this.person.address.country = this.inputs[0].Country;
     this.person.address.countryCode = this.inputs[0].CountryCode;
     if(this.inputs.length >1){
       for(var i=0;i<this.inputs.length;i++){
        this.position.positionCode = this.inputs[i].Positioncode;
        this.position.positionTitle = this.inputs[i].PositionTitle;
        this.person.positions.push(this.position);
       }
     }
}
```

and here is a sample of the data as it comes from the DB.

```
[ { SweepID: 1,
    IndivId: 404873,
    FirstName: 'Paul',
    PrefName: null,
    LastName: 'Person',
    Suffix: null,
    Language: 'EN',
    Addr1: '13120 Skidaway Place',
    Addr2: null,
    Addr3: null,
    City: 'Tarry Town',
    State: 'LOUISIANA           ',
    Zip: '70737',
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Country: 'United States',
    PrimaryPhoneType: 'Home',
    PrimaryPhone: '(225)572-2268',
    PrimaryEmailType: null,
    PrimaryEmail: null,
    PositionCode: 'GM',
    TrackingNumber: '000131960',
    PositionTitle: 'General Manager',
    AreaServed: '027',
    DistrictServed: null,
    TrackingID: null },
  { SweepID: 82257,
    IndivId: 404873,
    FirstName: 'Paul',
    PrefName: null,
    LastName: 'Person',
    Suffix: null,
    Language: 'EN',
    Addr1: '13120 Skidaway Place',
    Addr2: null,
    Addr3: null,
    City: 'Tarry Town',
    State: 'LOUISIANA',
    Zip: '11111',
    CountryCode: 'US',
    Country: 'United States',
    PrimaryPhoneType: 'Home',
    PrimaryPhone: '(555)555-5555',
    PrimaryEmailType: null,
    PrimaryEmail: null,
    PositionCode: 'PRCONT',
    TrackingNumber: '000131960',
    PositionTitle: 'Primary Contact',
    AreaServed: null,
    DistrictServed: null,
    TrackingID: null } ]
```

How can I work around this to where it will accept Null Values?

Comment: How have you initialized `person`?

Comment: To debug your problem you can do 2 things: (1) Show in the question the exact error message that you get; (2) comment out as many lines as possible in your code to get the minimum code that triggers the error (or replace the input data with dummy strings for as many fields as possible).

Comment: I determined the issue was that I forgot to import something into the component to allow it to work. Don't remember off hand, but I moved on. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

*I'm going out on a limb here...*

I suspect your actual problem is probably laying with `person`, it is that which is throwing your error. The response having `null` values should not throw such an error.

So when you have not initialized it properly it's trying to read property paths that do not exist, for example:

```
person.email.priEmailType
```

where `person` might be an empty object, but `email` is `undefined`, so when it's trying to read `priEmailType`, it can't since `email` is `undefined`.

The quick fix is to initialize the object as:

```
person = {email:{}, phone:{}, name:{}, address:{}}
```

So for example now we can try and read `priEmailType` since `email` is no longer `undefined`

You might want to make some helper method or something to at least map the values to your `person`, especially if you want to use it elsewhere.

Comment: Just wanted to leave an answer before going to bed, even tho I didn't yet get an answer to my comment. I suspect I have the right diagnosis tho :D If not, I'll delete...

Comment: Could you update the question with the actual error-message you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're on to it here:

`this.person.email.priEmailType = this.inputs[0].PrimaryEmailType || 'Not Provided';`

just do the same for the other fields as well:

`this.person.name.lastName = this.inputs[0].LastName || '';`

if LastName is null/undefined it will default to an empty string

Comment: the thing is that I did do the `||'';` thing, but it still gave the same error...